# Phonegap Cordova 2.0 onActivityResult not called

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

I am building an app in Phonegap 2.0 that calls an Intent to a form app using a modified WebIntent plugin. I can successfully send the user to the form app using `this.cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intCanvas, 0);` but once the user completes the activity they are dumped out to the home screen instead of returning to my app.

here is the code i'm using.

WebIntent.java

```
package com.borismus.webintent;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.text.Html;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

/**
 * WebIntent is a PhoneGap plugin that bridges Android intents and web
 * applications:
 * 
 * 1. web apps can spawn intents that call native Android applications. 2.
 * (after setting up correct intent filters for PhoneGap applications), Android
 * intents can be handled by PhoneGap web applications.
 * 
 * @author boris@borismus.com
 * 
 */
public class WebIntent extends Plugin {

private String onNewIntentCallback = null;
private String callback;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
/**
 * Executes the request and returns PluginResult.
 * 
 * @param action
 *            The action to execute.
 * @param args
 *            JSONArray of arguments for the plugin.
 * @param callbackId
 *            The callback id used when calling back into JavaScript.
 * @return A PluginResult object with a status and message.
 */
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
    try {
        if (action.equals("startActivity")) {
            if (args.length() != 1) {
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
            }

            // Parse the arguments
            JSONObject obj = args.getJSONObject(0);
            String type = obj.has("type") ? obj.getString("type") : null;
            Uri uri = obj.has("url") ? Uri.parse(obj.getString("url")) : null;
            JSONObject extras = obj.has("extras") ? obj.getJSONObject("extras") : null;
            Map<String, String> extrasMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // Populate the extras if any exist
            if (extras != null) {
                JSONArray extraNames = extras.names();
                for (int i = 0; i < extraNames.length(); i++) {
                    String key = extraNames.getString(i);
                    String value = extras.getString(key);
                    extrasMap.put(key, value);
                }
            }

            startActivity(obj.getString("action"), uri, type, extrasMap);
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);

        } else if(action.equals("startActivityForResult")) {
            if (args.length() != 1) {
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
            }
            this.callback = callbackId;
            // Parse the arguments
            JSONObject obj = args.getJSONObject(0);
            String type = obj.has("type") ? obj.getString("type") : null;
            Uri uri = obj.has("url") ? Uri.parse(obj.getString("url")) : null;
            JSONObject extras = obj.has("extras") ? obj.getJSONObject("extras") : null;
            Map<String, String> extrasMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // Populate the extras if any exist
            if (extras != null) {
                JSONArray extraNames = extras.names();
                for (int i = 0; i < extraNames.length(); i++) {
                    String key = extraNames.getString(i);
                    String value = extras.getString(key);
                    extrasMap.put(key, value);
                }
            }

            this.startActivityForResult(obj.getString("action"), uri, type, extrasMap);
            PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
            result.setKeepCallback(true);
            return result;

        } else if (action.equals("hasExtra")) {
            if (args.length() != 1) {
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
            }
            Intent i = ((DroidGap)this.cordova.getContext()).getIntent();
            String extraName = args.getString(0);
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, i.hasExtra(extraName));

        } else if (action.equals("getExtra")) {
            if (args.length() != 1) {
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
            }
            Intent i = ((DroidGap)this.cordova.getContext()).getIntent();
            String extraName = args.getString(0);
            if (i.hasExtra(extraName)) {
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, i.getStringExtra(extraName));
            } else {
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR);
            }
        } else if (action.equals("getUri")) {
            if (args.length() != 0) {
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
            }

            Intent i = ((DroidGap)this.cordova.getContext()).getIntent();
            String uri = i.getDataString();
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, uri);
        } else if (action.equals("onNewIntent")) {
            if (args.length() != 0) {
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
            }

            this.onNewIntentCallback = callbackId;
            PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
            result.setKeepCallback(true);
            return result;
        } else if (action.equals("sendBroadcast")) 
        {
            if (args.length() != 1) {
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
            }

            // Parse the arguments
            JSONObject obj = args.getJSONObject(0);

            JSONObject extras = obj.has("extras") ? obj.getJSONObject("extras") : null;
            Map<String, String> extrasMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // Populate the extras if any exist
            if (extras != null) {
                JSONArray extraNames = extras.names();
                for (int i = 0; i < extraNames.length(); i++) {
                    String key = extraNames.getString(i);
                    String value = extras.getString(key);
                    extrasMap.put(key, value);
                }
            }

            sendBroadcast(obj.getString("action"), extrasMap);
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
        }
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
    }
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (this.onNewIntentCallback != null) {
        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, intent.getDataString());
        result.setKeepCallback(true);
        this.success(result, this.onNewIntentCallback);
    }
}

void startActivity(String action, Uri uri, String type, Map<String, String> extras) {
    Intent i = (uri != null ? new Intent(action, uri) : new Intent(action));

    if (type != null && uri != null) {
        i.setDataAndType(uri, type); //Fix the crash problem with android 2.3.6
    } else {
        if (type != null) {
            i.setType(type);
        }
    }

    for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
        String value = extras.get(key);
        // If type is text html, the extra text must sent as HTML
        if (key.equals(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT) && type.equals("text/html")) {
            i.putExtra(key, Html.fromHtml(value));
        } else if (key.equals(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
            // allowes sharing of images as attachments.
            // value in this case should be a URI of a file
            i.putExtra(key, Uri.parse(value));
        } else if (key.equals(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL)) {
            // allows to add the email address of the receiver
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { value });
        } else {
            i.putExtra(key, value);
        }
    }
    this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(i);
}
void startActivityForResult(String action, Uri uri, String type, Map<String, String> extras) {
    System.out.println("startActivityForResult invoked");
    /*Intent i = (uri != null ? new Intent(action, uri) : new Intent(action));

    if (type != null && uri != null) {
        i.setDataAndType(uri, type); //Fix the crash problem with android 2.3.6
    } else {
        if (type != null) {
            i.setType(type);
        }
    }

    for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
        String value = extras.get(key);
        // If type is text html, the extra text must sent as HTML
        if (key.equals(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT) && type.equals("text/html")) {
            i.putExtra(key, Html.fromHtml(value));
        } else if (key.equals(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
            // allowes sharing of images as attachments.
            // value in this case should be a URI of a file
            i.putExtra(key, Uri.parse(value));
        } else if (key.equals(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL)) {
            // allows to add the email address of the receiver
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { value });
        } else {
            i.putExtra(key, value);
        }
    }*/
    //this.cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
    //this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, i, REQUEST_CODE);
    Intent intCanvas = new Intent("com.gocanvas.launchApp");
    intCanvas.setPackage("com.gocanvas");
    intCanvas.putExtra("Appname", "appname");
    intCanvas.putExtra("Username", "username");
    //System.out.println("intent call " + intCanvas);
    this.cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intCanvas, 0);
}



void sendBroadcast(String action, Map<String, String> extras) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(action);
    for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
        String value = extras.get(key);
        intent.putExtra(key, value);
    }

    ((DroidGap)this.cordova.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
}

/**
 * Called when the activity exits
 *
 * @param requestCode       The request code originally supplied to startActivityForResult(),
 *                          allowing you to identify who this result came from.
 * @param resultCode        The integer result code returned by the child activity through its setResult().
 * @param intent            An Intent, which can return result data to the caller (various data can be attached to Intent "extras").
 */
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            this.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK), this.callback);
        } else {
            this.error(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR), this.callback);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app.ivn"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" ></uses-sdk>
<supports-screens 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:resizeable="false"
android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".IVNActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:launchMode="standard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running out of memory? Even in this case, you usually get brought back to Cordova but the state is usually lost and you can't get the result from your activity.  Is this behaviour consistent across devices?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only test it on a ZTE Optik, as the Canvas App i am calling the intent to has a bug with the Nexus 7 on the latest android build. would the eclipse LogCat or Console show a memory issue message? i'm not seeing anything like that.

Comment: Yes, the logcat would show that.  Does this do this in the emulator? I'd trust the emulator far more than I'd trust what happens on the ZTE device, the kind of have a history of acting unpredictably.

Comment: I don't see anything in the log cat about memory.

I have no luck getting the emulator to function, so i have never used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was the ole issue with screen rotation reloading the app. I just needed to add     `android:configChanges="orientation"`
to the manifest. unfortunately this would have been solved sooner if everyone wasn't listing this option as if you could have multiple values in the configChanges option.

this errors out every time.
`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"`

Answer (score 4):

```
this.cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intCanvas, 0)
```

saw your answer for your problem.. but some of the Native Android guys who need to hook into PhoneGap may want to know the way you can get your Activity to come back to your plug in is to make sure that :

```
this.cordova.setActivityResultCallback(MyActivity.this);
```

is called before you do the `startActivityForResult()` call. Something that really was bothering me that no one seemed to have answered.

Comment: This worked for me with Cordova 3.1 and my custom plugin